# .Net equivalent for zc.buildout or leiningen

Tags: leiningen, buildout

I know [Uppercut](http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/) which is not quite the same. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

While buildout provides many Python and egg related services, it can do many other things, as many things as there are recipes for.  You can build CMMI software, process template files performing substitutions, install arbitrary scripts.  See PyPI for a [list of recipes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=recipe&submit=search).

So if all you want is a build tool, you san still use buildout.  If you're looking for more than that, then you should elaborate on your requirements.

Comment: How can use build out to build .net projects? maybe it's doable but it's not out of the box. I was looking for something .net specific that has the ability to resolve dependencies automatically like buildout and leigingen.

Comment: As I said, you might want to update your question to clarify.  Also, buildout doesn't do it's own dependency resolution, it just builds on setuptools/distribute for that, so dependency isn't it's primary goal.